# Use angularJS .component() but got no values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to angularJS and trying to get the following simple samples to work.  But when I ran it, I got a blank screen instead of "Hello world".  Help will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

angular-comp.js:

```
  angular.module('myApp').component('greetUser', {
      template: 'Hello, {{$ctrl.user}}!',
      controller: function GreetUserController() {
          this.user = 'world';
      }
 });
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AngularJS</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js">             </script>
    <script src="js/angularcomp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <greet-user></greet-user>
</body>
 </html>
```

Update:  I found the problem,  the version 1.4.5 doesn't support component.  I now use 1.6.1 and it works !!!!

Comment: I'm working on this.. wait a minute

Comment: you probably meant `angular.module('myApp', [])` instead of `angular.module('myApp')`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides here

`angular.module('myApp')`

where this should be

`angular.module('myApp',[])`

because you're creating a new module. If you don't pass the second Array argument, AngularJS will try to find your module instead of creating a new one.

try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>AngularJS</title>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <greet-user></greet-user>
  </body>

  <script>
    angular.module('myApp',[])
      .component('greetUser', {
        template: 'Hello, {{$ctrl.user}}!',
        controller: function GreetUserController() {
          this.user = 'world';
        }
      });

  </script>

</html>
```

Comment: - thiagoh I tried the solution, but still didn't see the "Hello world" on the web page.

Comment: I copied the above solution in my IDE, and ran it again but still didn't see the "Hello world" on the web page.

Comment: Did you include the last version of angular 1?